# What is the scale of this song? It only uses I, II, III, IV and V of the minor scale

Tags: theory, scales

[image]

The key note is C#. It looks like a minor scale but lacks VI and VII (only contains 5 tones). What is its scale? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Alex. Although this type of question ("what scale is this") is off-topic here, search the site for "pentatonic". There are quite a few such posts, and one or more should help you find the answer you need.

Comment: @Aaron Hi Aaron, thank you for your comment. I will try that. Should I remove this question if it looks off-topic?

Comment: Your call on that. At minimum, you could wait to see if others disagree with me about it being off topic. And policy-wise, I understand the site to be agnostic on deletion-or-not of off-topic questions.

Comment: Welcome! It could also be nice to read about [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Personally, I'm not even convinced that it's off-topic (it seems to qualify as "technical analysis of a specific, complete work, or well defined section thereof"), and also I generally prefer to see off-topic questions closed rather than deleted unless they're offensive or otherwise problematic. And yes, I'd call this pentatonic, even though it only uses four pitches (there's no B).

Comment: Oops, my bad—this is definitely *not* pentatonic, at least in the [standard sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatonic_scale).

Comment: @Aaron I am not aware of a common name for this particular pentatonic scale.  Are you?

Comment: @phoog "Pentatonic" was the wrong term for me to have used. "Pentascale" or "pentachord" are more common — first five notes of a major or minor scale.

Comment: @AndyBonner While it meets the letter of "technical analysis", it is clearly (IMO) not in the spirit of the kind of analysis of interest to the site.

Comment: Be better to ask what scale do these notes belong to? There's no compunction, (as Andy says) to use all the diatonic notes from a key - and a piece is said to be in a key, not a scale. Which puts this firmly into C#m - of some sort.

Comment: And normally Roman numerals signify chords - capitals are major. Better to write ^1 ^2 ^3 ^4 ^5 for actual notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement that a piece use all the pitches "available to it." Plenty of genres routinely use only two or three pitches. What we have here is a collection of five neighboring pitches:

> C# D# E F# G#

... with an intervallic spacing of whole step, half step, whole step, whole step.

This could be the beginning of multiple scales or modes (natural, harmonic, or melodic minor, dorian, etc.). It's unnecessary to pin it down; the most we can say is that the tonic is C# and that its mode is generally minor (from a bimodal perspective of modern tonal harmony).

Comment: "Pentatonic" was the wrong term for me to have used. "Pentascale" or "pentachord" are more common — first five notes of a major or minor scale.

Comment: @Aaron - although we're very familiar with the major and minor pentatonic scales, I'd argue that the very word means 5 tones, which then puts this into 'pentatonic'. Pentascale and pentachord may well be under that umbrella. The well-known pents were also known as 'gapped scales', which this one can't be. So, all pentatonic, I'd say.

Comment: @Tim If I had to split hairs, I'd say that the *piece* is "penta-something," but that doesn't necessarily nail down a scale or mode. We get into the speculation of "*if* this piece *had* an A, would it be sharp?" etc.